# Javascript getAttribute("innerHTML") returning null?

Tags: javascript, html, null, innerhtml

I'm making a website designer with html and javascript, but I ran into a problem: when I call getAttribute("innerHTML") on a

element, it returns null. I would like to acces the innerhtml property of an element *without* using`element.innerHTmL`

If anyone has a suggestion, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

edit: i have made a jsfiddle to show it. https://jsfiddle.net/7ajren18/
Although i kind of see how it returns null (you can't go `<p innerHTML = "hey there">example</p>`), i kinda it would return it in DOM perspective

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `element.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some properties on a JS representation of an HTML element map onto attributes (e.g. the `.src` property of an image maps onto the `src` attribute in HTML), `innerHTML` doesn't.

When you read it, a string is generated containing a HTML serialisation of the element's child nodes. When you write to it, the HTML is parsed and the nodes generated used to replace the existing child nodes.

It doesn't have any relationship to an attribute on the element. It is its own thing.  There is no reason for `getAttribute` to recognise it.